# Gitversion - what tag-prefix does

Tags: git, semantic-versioning, gitversion

According to official GitVersion documentation (https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/input/docs/configuration/),

> **tag-prefix** is a regex which is used to trim git tags before processing (eg v1.0.0). Default is [vV] though this is just for illustrative purposes as we do a IgnoreCase match and could be v.

**Questions**:

1. What tag-prefix does?
2. Is there a way to see/verify if tag-prefix is working fine or not without CI/CD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What tag-prefix does?

This is to get the version number without any kind of prefix (which is not a number).

It [can be overridden](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/blob/115f4739a65a491a828c3244287e3b58195d99c1/docs/input/docs/usage/cli/arguments.md#example-how-to-override-configuration-option-tag-prefix-to-use-prefix-custom) with:

```
GitVersion.exe /output json /overrideconfig tag-prefix=custom
```

That is one way to check if it has any effect: override it with a dummy value and see if the version extracted is "wrong".

The [OP Ranjan Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2375071/ranjan-kumar) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733460/gitversion-what-tag-prefix-does/67734862#comment119880809_67734862):

> `tag-prefix` is a regex that fetches the semantic version from your git tag.
> So once you release your change make sure to create a Git tag with released version.

Comment: Agree. Just wanted to add that `tag-prefix`  is a regex that fetches the semantic version from your git tag.  So once you release your change make sure to create a git tag with released version.

Comment: @RanjanKumar Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.